# $M^{2\times 2}(\mathbb{Z})$ has identity $e_1$, but a certain subring $R$ has another identity $e_2$ and $e_1 \notin R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm a bit confused. Consider the following situation:

> We know $M^{2\times 2}(\mathbb{Z})$ has an identity for $\cdot$ which is $$e_1 =\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}.$$
> Now consider the subring $$A = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
> x & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 \\
> \end{pmatrix}\mid x \in \mathbb{Z}\right\},$$
> which has identity element:$$e_2 =\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 \\
> \end{pmatrix}.$$

In my book on algebra, it says that if $1\in R$ and $S\subset R$ is a subring of $R$, then $1\in S$ needs to be met. But in this example, this is not the case. Can someone help with my confusion?

Comment: Well, $A$  is a ring (isomorphic to $\mathbf Z$), but *not* a subring of $M^{2\times 2}(\mathbf Z)$, by definition of a subring.

Comment: @Bernard Not if we are working in the category of nonunital rings.

Comment: Bourbaki's definition of a ring includes units. When you're considering  non-unital rings, it has to be specified. Anyway, when a ring is non-unital, there is a construction that adds a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of "ring" varies in whether it includes 1 (and even commutativity of multiplication). Generally, those who hold 1 isn't required for a ring will not require a subring to have the same 1. It's a matter of differing conventions.

On the other hand, if this occurs in the same book that says subrings must include the same 1, that's an issue.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. My book didn't say that if $1\in R$, the $1\in S$ *must* also be true. My book only says that *if* you require $1\in R$ in the definition of a ring, then you must too when defining subsets.

Comment: A reference is Bourbaki's treatise, *Algebra*,  Ch. I, §8, Definition 3.